# Bash: checking gzip using == or "| grep"

Tags: bash, grep

I have a simple question here. I have a file and want to check if it is gzipped or not. I've had cases where people rename files without .gz so I'm using `file $name` instead of looking for ".gz" in the filename. The output of `file $filname` gives a long string: **zip1.gz: gzip compressed data, was "zip1", from Unix, last modified: Fri Jan 26 11:01:59 2024**.

I have two commands that appear to both work.

```
if file $filename | grep -q gzip ; then

if [[ $(file $filename) == *"gzip"* ]] ; then
```

Which way is preferred?

I also don't know why the first method works. `file $filename` outputs a string, correct? Then that string is piped to the input of `grep`. I thought `grep` accepts a file as an input, not a string.

Comment: The first one is good and concise. But don't forget to "quote" variables.

Comment: many cmds can read from std-in and `grep` (thankfully) is one of them. The `-q` means ***quiet**, so the only thing it will do is return true (`0`) if the search target it found and false (`1`) if not.

Comment: `grep` [defaults to reading stdin](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) if no file argument is given (unless it's a recursive search). If you want to be explicit, use a filename of `-`. You could also write this as `grep -q gzip <(file $filename)` in `bash`, if your stdin was otherwise being used in, say, a loop.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
if file -i "$file" | grep -q 'application/gzip'; then
    [...]
else
    echo >&2 "$file is not a gzip file"
fi
```

or

```
mytype=$(file -i "$file")
case "$mytype" in
    *application/gzip*)
        [...]
    ;;
    *)
        echo >&2 "$file is not a gzip file"
    ;;
esac
```

Both solutions don't need [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you even can use [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) `sh` with them.

Comment: I would not overwrite `type` builtin

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```bash
if gunzip --test "${file}" 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then
  echo "This is a gzipped file!"
else
  echo "This is NOT a gzipped file."
fi
```